# Stop table from overlapping image

Tags: html, css, overlap, css-tables

I have a table that is supposed to be positioned under an image on the homepage of my site. It looks great on most computers but on some smaller screens the table overlaps the image. I can keep pushing the table down put that just makes it look worse on bigger screens. Is there any way to set the positioning so it is always a certain percentage under the image? Or something else along those lines maybe.

Here's the css for the image and the table:

```
#headshot{
position: fixed;
top: 16.5%;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -200px;
}

#outline {
border:0px;
align:center;
position: absolute;
top: 65%;
left: 25%;
}
```

Comment: Floating them, min-height, making them consecutive elements, media-queries... can you provide a working (showing the problem) [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.com/) so we can better see what you mean, please? Include there as little code as you can to reproduce your problem.

Comment: You're mixing fixed/absolute positioning. things will over/under-lap at some point no matter what you do.

Comment: @FranciscoPresencia http://jsfiddle.net/B6KqD/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see from your jsfiddle, you want to position the image centered ( `align: center;` is not valid css ) and have the table just behind it. I need to say that your html was pretty messy, combining things with `<h1>Something</h2>` and similars, which is not valid html. I recommend trying the [w3 html validator](http://validator.w3.org/) to make sure your code is sharp.

That said, here's your working jsfiddle:

> **http://jsfiddle.net/B6KqD/1/**

I added a wrapper and changed the css to:

```
#wrapper {
    margin: 16.5% auto 0;
}
#outline {
    border:0px;
    margin: 20px auto 0;
}
h1 {
    font-family: title;
    font-size: 20pt;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    text-align: center;
}
h2 {
    font-family: title;
    font-size: 40pt;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    text-align: center;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: title;
    src: url(http://nickgertler.com/resources/champagnelimousines.woff);
    font-weigt: 100;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! And I know I need to clean the code up a lot. I haven't done any work in a while and I've been working on a tight deadline so I've just had to go. Thanks a lot though

Answer (score 0):

If it's only about the size of screen, you can use the CSS3 media queries property

```
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {

  table {

  ..property..
  }
}
```